# Interesting permutations problem . Show that there are $2^n \cdot n!$ ways of....

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I found this cool problem from an elementary pure math book.(I am trying my best to translate that from Sinhalese to English):

> There are $2n$ number of posts fixed on the circumference of a circular ground, so there are two posts sitting on the each side of a diameter. A man starts running from a place on the ground, touches $n$ different posts, where touching both the posts between any diameter is not allowed, then runs back to the initial position. Show that there are $2^n.n!$ different ways he could do that.

Firstly, I drew a tree diagram branched considering the fact whether a post is touched or not, but for only first $n$ posts. Then I found that there are $2^n$ different ways the man can do that. That is including the outcome of not touching any of the first $n$ posts. Then I got stuck.

How efficient was my approach? Was it incorrect?

Please, explain in detail the correct method(s). I cannot sleep without knowing the method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that the requirements that the man selects $n$ posts and that he may only select one of the two posts at the end of each diameter means he selects one of the two ends of each of the $n$ diameters.  There are $n!$ orders in which he could select the diameters.  For each diameter, he has $2$ choices of which end to touch.  Hence, there are $n!2^n$ ways he could touch $n$ different posts if touching both posts at the ends of the diameter is prohibited.